# Overwrite plugin files?

Tags: wordpress

I want to overwrite the file `plugins/the-events-calendar/tickets/meta-box.php` of the plugin [The Events Calendar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/screenshots/).

I followed the tutorial [Overwrite Plugin Files](http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/using-template-files/) but this is not working for me.

How can I overwrite this file?

i want to add new metabox in evetns Ticket section how can i do without edit the plugin file other wise overwrite that plugin files.

Comment: specific your question. "not working" is the best answer if you dont need help.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss But this is not working for me. i used events calendar plugin. please check this http://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/screenshots/

Comment: You can make a little script with `Regular Expression` to print out all used actions,.. Thats another way

Comment: @renishkhunt: the file you want to overwrite is it a paid add-on? if yes how we can help you without have the files in question?

Comment: @aSeptik YES This is paid plugin. but there is nothing matter how to overwrite any plugin file. that doesn't matter which plugin i am used i overwrite all plugins file. how can i do that?

Comment: Dear, i understand that you want to overwrite that file and it can be done for sure. The problem is that the meaning "overwrite" itself do not tell/explain us anything about what you are going to do! Literally "overwrite" means: write over an existing file by replacing completely the old content with new content; this can be done simply by replacing `meta-box.php` with an empy file. Since i doubt that you want an empty file, you should tell us what `part/function/code` of that file you want to replace. hope this help understand the point. We need that file, you should send it via mail...

Answer (score 5):

I don't have the paid Ticket plugin you refer to, but I took a bit of time to skim through the available GitHub code:

https://github.com/moderntribe/the-events-calendar/

It looks like the overwrite option (i.e. moving a file from the plugin folder to the `tribe-events/` folder within your current theme directory) only applies to the *views* templates in:

https://github.com/moderntribe/the-events-calendar/tree/master/views

You can see for example the definition of the `getTemplateHierarchy()` function [here](https://github.com/moderntribe/the-events-calendar/blob/master/lib/tickets/tribe-tickets.php).

But this overwrite option doesn't apply to the `/admin-views/tickets/meta-box.php` file, since it's included [here](https://github.com/moderntribe/the-events-calendar/blob/master/lib/tickets/tribe-tickets-pro.php) with the default PHP `include()`:

```
 include $this->path . 'admin-views/tickets/meta-box.php';
```

through this method call [here](https://github.com/moderntribe/the-events-calendar/blob/master/lib/tickets/tribe-tickets-metabox.php):

```
TribeEventsTicketsPro::instance()->do_meta_box( $post_id );
```

where the metabox comes from:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 
            array( 'TribeEventsTicketsMetabox', 'maybe_add_meta_box' ) );
```

Looking at the source of this [file](https://github.com/moderntribe/the-events-calendar/blob/master/lib/tickets/tribe-tickets.php), I found this part:

```
<?php do_action( 'tribe_events_tickets_metabox_advanced', 
                 get_the_ID(), NULL ); ?>
```

This might be what you are looking for, if you want to add some extra tickets UI to the event editor. Try to hook into this `tribe_events_tickets_metabox_advanced` action to add your extra UI.

Hope this help.

Comment: Any tips on how exactly to hook into tribe_events_tickets_metabox_advanced? All I want to do is add a meta box to the edit page, but it seems like quite a challenge.

Comment: It sounds like you want to call a meta-box inside another meta-box. You could try to run the meta-box callback function directly inside the `tribe_events_tickets_metabox_advanced` hook. The generalization  might be an interesting new question i.e. how to call a metabox inside another one? @GavinSimpson

Comment: Yes you are spot on. Already done a lot of customising of the events calendar, and support is minimal, even on SO, so a few questions and answer would help others a lot. Thanks for the response.